# Лишний пробел в строке достижения

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, локализация, привилегии

В достижениях может быть текст:

> Вы заработали привилегию «защищённые **вопросы »!** Узнать об этом больше можно в Справке.

> [image: скриншот]

Там пробел лишний. Исправьте, пожалуйста.

Comment: Вот здесь похоже в переводе лишний пробел в конце: https://www.transifex.com/stack-exchange/stack-overflow-ru/translate/#ru/english/41447135 Перевод отмечен как проверенный.

Comment: @insolor любопытно, что после исключения пробела список ревизий не поменялся. Даже нельзя теперь NickVolynkin обвинить!

Answer (score 9):

Пробел убрали. Должно пофикситься после подгрузки Transifex и пересборки сайта.

Comment: [Не пофиксилось](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6BEih.png) :(

Comment: всё ещё [не пофиксилось](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AoWEc.png) ((

Comment: @user268670 а Вы как проверяете?

Comment: иногда завожу новый аккаунт, вот вчера на нём получил это достижение

Comment: @user268670 это 10 реп надо набрать? Странно, что это проявляется. Строки переведены давно уже.

Comment: Да, 10 репутации. Странно, да

Comment: @user268670 есть предположение, что присутствует глюк Transifex, и строки, отличающиеся только пробелами он не считает разными, а потому не подгружает. Выполнил еще одну итерацию, посмотрим как пойдет, но это уже не раньше понедельника можно проверить.